# Sqlite select different rows as one

Tags: sqlite

I've been searching the page for possible solutions but I can't find it anywhere.. What I need is pretty simple I need multiple rows to be displayed into one. I have tried || + ||, etc.

```
select c_category_in, c_data_services, c_dispositivos, c_averia as 'Sub-Category', count() as 'Total'
from tickets
group by c_category_in,c_averia,c_data_services,c_dispositivos 
having (Total > 1)
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A75aH.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean "display" and "into one". SQLite itself is for data retrieval. So what exactly do you want to retrieve from the database? How many rows? What should each of them contain?

Comment: What I need is c_data_services and c_dispositivos be displayed in sub-category so I can do a report without multiple rows.

Comment: I still don't understand. You must know that a single query to SQLite will return a set of rows, each having the same number of columns. It is basically just a table that you get as the results. Try maybe adding sample data and result that you *would like* to get from this data as opposed to what you *currently* get (presented in the screenshot).

Comment: I'd like it to display as: C_category_in Sub-Category Total The data in Sub-category must contains c_data_services or c_dispositivos.

Comment: [link]http://imgur.com/zgCmoxa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [COALESCE function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce) returns the first non-`NULL` value:

```
SELECT c_category_in,
       COALESCE(c_data_services, c_dispositivos) AS SubCategory,
       COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM tickets
GROUP BY c_category_in, SubCategory
HAVING Total > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments I would recommend taking a `UNION` of two separate groupings:

1. Grouping the data by `c_data_services`
2. Grouping the data by `c_dispositivos`

This results in a `SELECT` as following:

```
select c_category_in, c_data_services as 'Sub-Category', count() as 'Total'
from tickets
group by c_category_in, c_data_services
having (Total > 1)
union all
select c_category_in, c_dispositivos as 'Sub-Category', count() as 'Total'
from tickets
group by c_category_in, c_dispositivos
having (Total > 1)
```